# Java Reflection - Construct Object & Add to List

Tags: java

A method with this signature constructs an object of class `objClass` which is somewhere in the `BaseModel` hierarchy, and adds it to the list with `? extends BaseModel` objects.

```
public void constructAndAdd(List<? extends BaseModel> list, Class objClass)
{
   BaseModel newObject = (BaseModel)objClass.newInstance();
   list.add(newObject);
}
```

Error:

```
The method add(capture#2-of ? extends BaseModel) in the type List<capture#2-of ? extends BaseModel> is not applicable for the arguments (BaseModel)
```

I wish I could do

```
? extends BaseModel newObject = (? extends BaseModel)objClass.newInstance();
```

but that syntax is wrong.

Comment: Try changing "List<? extends BaseModel>" list to "List<BaseModel> list"

Comment: But my list contains object of a subtype of BaseModel, not BaseModel itself. The solution provided by SLaks is correct, I have to specify generics in the method signature.

Comment: @Pshemo: Yes, because `T` will be that derived class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler cannot know that the `?` is the same type of the class.

You need to make the method itself generic, so that you can actually refer to that type:

```
public <T extends BaseModel> void constructAndAdd(List<? super T> list, Class<? extends T> objClass) {
    list.add(objClass.newInstance());
}
```

Once you do that, you don't need any casts at all.

Answer (score 2):

`List<? extends BaseModel> list` can hold lists of any type of elements extending BaseModel. So lets say that user passed to it list of `FooBaseModel` elements, where `FooBaseModel` is class which extends `BaseModel` but introduces some additional fields/methods. Now would it be safe if we could add to that list *any* `BaseModel`?

No because when we use `list.get();`, we expect it to return instance of `FooBaseModel` on which we could safely invoke these additional methods.

Another problem is that `objClass.newInstance()` could return other type which extends `BaseModel` but behaves in different way than `FooBaseModel` would expect.

So you can't add any element to list defined as `List<? extends OtherType>`.